# Equality 4 bit with 4 bit by IC 74181 (ALU)

Tags: proteus, alu

Pin 14 in IC 74181 when 2 numbers (4bit) equal this pin must be high.

This pin is open collector. I connect this pin to Vcc & Res but not high or red.

I've created this circuit in Protheus.

What should I do high on this pin?

[image]

Comment: I presume you mean the 74181 not the 7481 in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to know how to connect an LED to the A=B output so that it is ON when the output is high.

Actually, you've done it wrong for the other 5 outputs as well, since TTL (and LSTTL) does not source current very well, but needs to sink it. So try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp0vfU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you have 6 outputs to monitor, and a 74LS04 has 6 inverters, it's a perfect fit.

Comment: @gabe - Also note that "regular" (non-buffer) LSTTL is not really intended to sink more than (nominally) 8 mA, so you can play with the LED resistors, but don't let them get much less than the indicated values.

Comment: in data sheet ic 74181 written "The A = B output from the LS181 goes HIGH when all four F
outputs are HIGH and can be used to indicate logic
equivalence over four bits when the unit is in the subtract
mode" i mean A=B output was high without connecting led.

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you so much user WhatRoughBeast.your Description was Correct.